# Laravel Unit Testing - Controllers

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am quite new to Laravel and have been reading the documentation on testing, however I am not sure how I would go about Unit Testing the Controller I have posted below. Any advice on how I would go about this is much appreciated.
The controller below is the CRUD controller I created for Booking Forms.

```
class BookingFormsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $bookingforms = BookingForm::orderBy('surgeryDate', 'asc')->paginate(5);
        return view('bookingforms.index')->with('bookingforms', $bookingforms);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('bookingforms.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $booking)
    {
      $this->validate($booking, [
      'requestID' => 'required',
      'patientID' => 'required',
      'patientForename' => 'required',
      'patientSurname'=> 'required',
      'patientSex' => 'required',
      'patientDOB' => 'required',
      'surgeryType' => 'required',
      'surgeryDate' => 'required',
      'performingSurgeon' => 'required',
      'TheatreRoomID' => 'required',
      'patientUrgency' => 'required',
      'patientNotes' => 'required',
      'bloodGroup' => 'required'
      ]);

      // Create new Booking Form
      $bookingform = new Bookingform;
      $bookingform->requestID = $booking->input('requestID');
      $bookingform->bookingID = $booking->input('bookingID');
      $bookingform->patientID = $booking->input('patientID');
      $bookingform->patientForename = $booking->input('patientForename');
      $bookingform->patientSurname = $booking->input('patientSurname');
      $bookingform->patientSex = $booking->input('patientSex');
      $bookingform->patientDOB = $booking->input('patientDOB');
      $bookingform->surgeryType = $booking->input('surgeryType');
      $bookingform->surgeryDate = $booking->input('surgeryDate');
      $bookingform->performingSurgeon = $booking->input('performingSurgeon');
      $bookingform->TheatreRoomID = $booking->input('TheatreRoomID');
      $bookingform->patientUrgency = $booking->input('patientUrgency');
      $bookingform->patientNotes = $booking->input('patientNotes');
      $bookingform->bloodGroup = $booking->input('bloodGroup');
      $bookingform->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

      //Save Booking form

      $bookingform->save();

      //redirect
      return redirect('/bookingforms')->with('success', 'Booking Submitted');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($bookingID)
    {
        $bookingform = BookingForm::find($bookingID);
        return view('bookingforms.show')->with('bookingform', $bookingform);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($bookingID)
    {
        $bookingform = BookingForm::find($bookingID);
        //check for correct user_id
        if(auth()->user()->id !==$bookingform->user_id){
            return redirect('/bookingforms')->with('danger', 'This is not your booking, please contact the Booker.');
        }
        return view('bookingforms.edit')->with('bookingform', $bookingform);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $booking, $bookingID)
    {
      $this->validate($booking, [
      'patientID' => 'required',
      'patientForename' => 'required',
      'patientSurname'=> 'required',
      'patientSex' => 'required',
      'patientDOB' => 'required',
      'surgeryType' => 'required',
      'surgeryDate' => 'required',
      'performingSurgeon' => 'required',
      'TheatreRoomID' => 'required',
      'patientUrgency' => 'required',
      'patientNotes' => 'required',
      'bloodGroup' => 'required'
      ]);

      // Create new Booking Form
      $bookingform = Bookingform::find($bookingID);
      $bookingform->bookingID = $booking->input('bookingID');
      $bookingform->patientID = $booking->input('patientID');
      $bookingform->patientForename = $booking->input('patientForename');
      $bookingform->patientSurname = $booking->input('patientSurname');
      $bookingform->patientSex = $booking->input('patientSex');
      $bookingform->patientDOB = $booking->input('patientDOB');
      $bookingform->surgeryType = $booking->input('surgeryType');
      $bookingform->surgeryDate = $booking->input('surgeryDate');
      $bookingform->performingSurgeon = $booking->input('performingSurgeon');
      $bookingform->TheatreRoomID = $booking->input('TheatreRoomID');
      $bookingform->patientUrgency = $booking->input('patientUrgency');
      $bookingform->patientNotes = $booking->input('patientNotes');
      $bookingform->bloodGroup = $booking->input('bloodGroup');
      $bookingform->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

      //Save Booking form

      $bookingform->save();

      //redirect
      return redirect('/bookingforms')->with('success', 'Booking Updated');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($bookingID)
    {
        $bookingform = Bookingform::find($bookingID);
        if(auth()->user()->id !==$bookingform->user_id){
            return redirect('/bookingforms')->with('danger', 'This is not your booking, please contact the Booker.');
        }
        $bookingform->delete();
        return redirect('/bookingforms')->with('success', 'Booking Removed');
    }
```

Comment: Typically you'd make an [HTTP test](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests) which hits the endpoint you need to unit test.

Answer (score 1):

The controller you wrote is a bit hard to test, as it is tightly coupled to the `Eloquent` model. You would better decouple it by adding a repository layer and inject it into your controller.

BTW: you can use [fillable attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) to avoid writing a lot of code just to fill the attributes of your `BookingForm`

Now for example you may do the following:

Create A BookingFormRepository interface:

```
interface BookingFormRepository
{
    public function all();
    public function create(array $attributes);

    // etc ....

}
```

Create an implementation of the `BookingFormRepository`:

```
class BookingFormRepositoryImpl implements BookingRepository 
{
    public function all()
    {
         return BookingForm::all();
    }

    public function create(array $attributes)
    {
        // Use fillable attributes for better readability
        $record = BookingForm::create($attributes);
        return $record;
    }

    // Implement other methods ....
}
```

In the `AppServiceProvider` in the `register` method bind your implementation:

```
App::bind(BookingFormRepository::class, BookingFormRepositoryImpl::class);
```

Then in your controller, inject the `BookingRepository` interface:

```
class BookingFormController extends Controller {

    private $bookingFormRepository;

    public function __construct(BookingFormRepository $bookingRepo)
    {
        $this->bookingFormRepository = $bookingRepo;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $bookings = $this->bookingFormRepository->all();
        return view('bookingform.index', $bookings);
    }

    // .. other methods ... like `store`
}
```

Now the controller will be easy to test, just mock the `BookingRepository` and make call assertions on it:

```
class BookingFormControllerTest extends TestCase
{
     public function testIndexBookingForm()
     {
          // Arrange

          $repository = Mockery::mock('BookingRepository');
          $repository->shouldReceive('all')->once()
              ->andReturn(['foobar']);
          App::instance('BookingRepository', $repository);


          // Act, Replace with your right url ...
          $this->get('bookings');

          // Assert
          $this->assertResponseOk();
          $this->assertViewHas('bookingforms.index', ['foobar']);
     }
}
```

I recommand reading the Taylor Otwell book "Laravel from aprentice to Artisan".

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testBookingFormsIndex()
    {
        $response = $this->get('index');
        $response->assertStatus('200');
    }

    public function testBookingFormsCreate()
    {
        $response = $this->get('create');
        $response->assertStatus('200');
    }

}
```

Like i said, the above is a basic example that is based on the example from the HTTP Test documentation from laravel.

More information can be found here:
**https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests**

I would also recommend using the laravel Requests to validate your form inputs, this keeps your controller clean and places the code where is belongs. 
More information on this topic can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: Thank you! I seem to be getting a 302 response instead of 200, would this be due to user authentication being required for these routes?

Comment: No, if the user isnt authenticated you would get a 403. Take a look at this website, it explains the 302. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302